# Translate github flavored markdown regex from ruby to python

Tags: python, ruby, regex, markdown

I'm trying to get an implementation of github flavored markdown working in python, with no luck... I don't have much in the way of regex skills.

Here's the ruby code from [github](https://github.com/github/github-flavored-markdown/blob/gh-pages/code.rb#L17):

```
# in very clear cases, let newlines become <br /> tags
text.gsub!(/(\A|^$\n)(^\w[^\n]*\n)(^\w[^\n]*$)+/m) do |x|
  x.gsub(/^(.+)$/, "\\1  ")
end
```

And here's what I've come up with so far in python 2.5:

```
def newline_callback(matchobj):
    return re.sub(r'^(.+)$','\1 ',matchobj.group(0))     
text = re.sub(r'(\A|^$\n)(^\w[^\n]*\n)(^\w[^\n]*$)+', newline_callback, text)
```

There just doesn't seem to be any effect at all :-/

If anyone has a fully working implementation of [github flavored markdown](http://github.github.com/github-flavored-markdown/) in python, other than [this one](http://gregbrown.co.nz/code/githib-flavoured-markdown-python-implementation/) (doesn't seem to work for newlines), I'd love to hear about it. I'm really most concerned about the newlines.

These are the tests for the regex, from github's ruby code:

```
>>> gfm_pre_filter('apple\\npear\\norange\\n\\nruby\\npython\\nerlang')
'apple  \\npear  \\norange\\n\\nruby  \\npython  \\nerlang'
>>> gfm_pre_filter('test \\n\\n\\n something')
'test \\n\\n\\n something'
>>> gfm_pre_filter('# foo\\n# bar')
'# foo\\n# bar'
>>> gfm_pre_filter('* foo\\n* bar')
'* foo\\n* bar'
```

Comment: Please post an example of something that **should** work.  What's **expected** and what you're really getting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That Ruby version has **multiline modifier** in the regex, so you need to do the same in python:

```
def newline_callback(matchobj):
    return re.sub(re.compile(r'^(.+)$', re.M),r'\1  ',matchobj.group(0))     

text = re.sub(re.compile(r'(\A|^$\n)(^\w[^\n]*\n)(^\w[^\n]*$)+', re.M), newline_callback, text)
```

So that code will (like the Ruby version) add two spaces after before newline, except if we have two newlines (paragraph).

Are those test string you gave correct? That file you linked has this, and it works with that fixed code:

```
"apple\npear\norange\n\nruby\npython\nerlang"
->
"apple  \npear  \norange\n\nruby  \npython  \nerlang"
```

Comment: Thanks a ton... Could you point out to to me where the multiline modifier is in the Ruby regex? It's not /m, is it?

Comment: Yes it's that /m. /foo/m is a short of Regexp.new("foo", Regexp::MULTILINE), see "Regular Expression Options": http://ruby-doc.org/docs/ruby-doc-bundle/ProgrammingRuby/book/language.html#UK

Answer (score 0):

```
return re.sub(r'^(.+)$',r'\1 ',matchobj.group(0))
                       ^^^--------------------------- you forgot this.
```

Comment: Yes, but that didn't really solve the problem... I've added tests that need to pass when the regex is applied.